# 3D template for irobot-create

Tags: irobot-create, 3d-printing

Does anyone know where I can find the template of the face plate for the Create 2.0?

I would like to print or laser-cut.

Answer (score 0):

This template can be found in a link within https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Deco_Cover_Modification.pdf : it's https://www.irobot.com/~/media/mainsite/pdfs/about/stem/create/createdrilltemplate.pdf.

Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.

Comment: Thank you so much, Do you know if there is any website where I can find the 3D model (stl) to make the modifications there and then print it.

Comment: There's almost what you need here. https://www.thingiverse.com/irobot/designs